Ubuntu 22.04 Does not Recognize Second Monitor
I have a server with a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (release 22.04) and I am trying to hook up two monitors in extend mode. This server only has a single display port out so I bought a hub which is supposed to allow distributing a single display port source to two displays using Multi-Stream Transport.
When I plug the Ubuntu server display port into the hub, and run the hub's two display port out ports to two monitors (each with a display port input), the two monitors mirror the same display and only one monitor is shown in the display settings.

I did not build this server but I found the graphics card:
    % lspci | grep VGA                   
16:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 164e (rev ca)

Which I think supports mult-stream-transport?
A few more related command outputs in case they are helpful
% find /dev -group video
/dev/dri/card1
/dev/fb0

% glxinfo | grep -i vendor           
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
OpenGL vendor string: AMD

% glxinfo | grep -i "vendor\|rendering"
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: AMD (0x1002)
OpenGL vendor string: AMD

% lsmod | grep "kms\|drm"
drm_exec               12288  1 amdgpu
drm_buddy              20480  1 amdgpu
drm_suballoc_helper    20480  1 amdgpu
drm_ttm_helper         12288  1 amdgpu
ttm                   110592  2 amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper
drm_display_helper    237568  1 amdgpu
cec                    94208  1 drm_display_helper

% xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 2560 x 1600, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 2560x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 640mm x 400mm
   2560x1600     59.94*+
   2048x1536     59.90 ...

I also checked the "Additional Drivers" tab in Software & Updates to see if there are any proprietary graphics drivers I could install but there was nothing listed in there. It shows "No additional drivers available." I also tried running the one display port to one monitor and daisy chaining the monitors using the upstream and downstream display ports but got the same mirroring behavior with just one monitor showing up in Display Settings. I have tried rebooting on several occasions and looked at many seemingly related posts but the solutions have not applied or have not worked for me. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as mirror mode is not very helpful to me.
